# Placeholder for conditionally rendered UI elements in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

What is the appropriate placeholder for rendering UI elements in Shiny?  I want parts of the UIs to be rendered based on conditions that are determined in global.R, so not `renderUI`.  I thought using an empty list or taglist might work, but it doesn't seem to do the job.

Here is an example, when `init` is TRUE, the first box should be rendered, when `init` is FALSE only the second box should be rendered.  This second part isn't working quite right.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

## Globally set
init <- FALSE # sometimes TRUE

ui <- tagList(
    fluidPage(
        tabBox(
            ## What is the appropriate placeholder here?
            if (init) {
                tabPanel(
                    title='Bad box',
                    box(selectInput('id', 'Appear if TRUE', 1:10))
                )
            } else 
                list(),
            tabPanel(
                title='Good box',
                box(selectInput('id1', 'Always Apper', letters))
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work? I made a list with both boxes and then subset it in a `do.call` to add one or both of the boxes depending on the `init` value.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

## Globally set
init <- FALSE # sometimes TRUE

box_element <- list(
  tabPanel(
  title='Bad box',
  box(selectInput('id', 'Appear if TRUE', 1:10))),

  tabPanel(
    title='Good box',
    box(selectInput('id1', 'Always Apper', letters))
  ))


ui <- tagList(
  fluidPage(
   do.call(tabBox,box_element[(2-init):2])
  )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

The package [shinyjs](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs) has functions to show/hide elements based on a specific condition, and that condition can be a reactive value. It's used exactly for cases like this, when you want to hide/show in the server rather than in the UI.  Here's a simple example, it will show a text input whenever the number in the numeric input is odd.  You can of course change that condition to be anything you want.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  numericInput("num", "Show a text input when the number is odd", 0),
  hidden(textInput("text", "Text"))
)
server <- function(session, input, output) {
  observe({
    toggle(id = "text", condition = (input$num %% 2 == 1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is it a variable that will actually change its value from time to time or between different user sessions? I don't think it will work like that very well. If I understand shiny correctly, the UI portion doesn't actually run every time, it only runs ONCE, and all the users that connect to the app. For example, put a `Sys.time()` inside your UI, and open 3 different sessions, a few seconds apart, and you'll see that all 3 sessions have the same time shown in the UI. I think it'd make more sense to control the visibility in the server

Comment: I see. You can use inline CSS to hide the one you don't want with an if statement, although it would still technically be rendered, just not shown.  Something like `div("only show if init is true", style = ifelse(init, "display: block;", "display: none;"))`